# Xampp not working on Linux

Tags: linux, xampp, zend-framework2

I recently installed Linux and Xampp server.  I had been working on it last night and this morning without any problems.  This morning I started working the zend framework.  Everything was going well until I had to restart my computer.

After restarting, when I tried to access localhost I was getting this message in my browser:

**It works!**

**This is the default web page for this server.**

**The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.**

I have restarted xampp and apache.  In the httpd.conf file I have changed the port from 80 to 8080. I'm running php 5.4.6.  I have also reinstalled xampp just to be sure.

As far as I can tell, the only alterations I made outside of the zend project directory were the httpd.conf file.  I changed "allowOverride None" to "allowOverride AllowAll".  I also installed Composer and phpUnit, though I can't imagine how they would have caused the problem.

Any help you can throw my way would be great.  I'm very stuck with this.

Comment: Could you check Apache website access logs? They'd provide some info about what kind of page gets loaded. Look for them in `/var/log`.

Comment: On which directory is your (v)host pointing? Make sure it is pointing to the right directory.

Comment: If you changed the port to 8080, surely you should be looking at `localhost:8080`?

Comment: check for .htaccess file whether its there or not , I am sure it might have got deleted or lost its permissions

Comment: allowOverride AllowAll <- I'm sure this needs to be allowOverride All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default content of index.php or index.html file. Try rename these files.